# Is there any complete standalone installer for IE-9 which don't use internet to install?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9, setup

I tried to find this but still not success. I'm searching a complete offline installers for Windows-7 of IE-9 which should not check for updates to install. If anyone knows please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the offline installers directly from here:

- [Download Internet Explorer 9 - Microsoft Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages)

In addition, you need to install the prerequisite, or the installer will have to fetch it from the internet.

You can find it here:

- [A performance and functionality update is available for Windows 7 and for Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2454826)

For more information, consult:

- [Prerequisites for installing Internet Explorer 9](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2399238)

Comment: MS took down that IE9 installer page. How convenient for them to make a bad browser, and then force us all to play pretend that their mistake doesn't still exist in the wild.

Comment: Also, Others seem to have had some luck with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532261/how-to-install-ie9-internet-explorer-9-on-windows-7-despite-80092004-error

Answer (score 0):

You can download via oldversion website.

http://www.oldversion.com/windows/download/internet-explorer-9-0-7-x64

The file size of the x64 for windows 7 that I just downloaded is 34 MB.
Worked on my freshly installed Windows 7 ultimate 64-bit

Btw, they also have IE 6, IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10 and IE11 in there

Good luck :)